# Some links ignoring EventListener

Tags: javascript, iphone-standalone-web-app, iphone-web-app

## Update

User Quentin helped me solve it. The lightbox had a `event.stopPropagation();` in the function which prevented the eventlistener from bubbling up. After removing it the links worked properly.

I used this comment with honyovk's addition to replace the stopPropagation with a more elegant function: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1089622/3461722

---

### Question

I have a webapp for iOS in which I use an EventListener to prevent links from opening in Safari. This works flawless for 99% of the links, but a few specific links still open in Safari for some reason unknown to me.

This is my Javascript:

```
// Mobile Safari in standalone mode
if(("standalone" in window.navigator) && window.navigator.standalone){

    // If you want to prevent remote links in standalone web apps opening Mobile Safari, change 'remotes' to true
    var noddy, remotes = false;

    document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {

        noddy = event.target;

        // Bubble up until we hit link or top HTML element. Warning: BODY element is not compulsory so better to stop on HTML
        while(noddy.nodeName !== "A" && noddy.nodeName !== "HTML") {
            noddy = noddy.parentNode;
        }

        if('href' in noddy && noddy.href.indexOf('http') !== -1 && (noddy.href.indexOf(document.location.host) !== -1 || remotes))
        {
            event.preventDefault();
            document.location.href = noddy.href;
        }

    },false);
}
```

The links that fail to open in the webapp are nothing special, and other links on the page work without problem. An example of a not properly working link:

```
<a href="upgrademine.php?m=green" class="button bgreen">Buy</a>
```

This link is opened in a lightbox, but on other pages I have similar links also in a lightbox and they work fine. I have several popups with roughly the same link, only the "green" is different and some have an extra "&time=1", they all fail to open in the webapp.

Is there someone who can find fault with this code?

Comment: You probably have some code stopping propagation, but you haven't shown enough to tell.

Comment: I do have code stopping propagation now you mention it! I have a     `function noclick(event) { event.stopPropagation(); };` somewhere for my lightbox, could this be causing it? I'm quite new to javascript.

Comment: Yes. That's the point of `event.stopPropagation`.

Comment: Well the lightbox has a black background that when clicked closes the lightbox. I have used `event.stopPropagation` on the div with the actual lightbox content to prevent the lightbox from closing when I click anything within that content. Is there a way to only apply it to that div and not the children? So that the children still propagate.

Comment: Removing the "close when the background is clicked" code instead of trying to stop it being triggered would seem to make more sense. I would just have the normal functionality though.

Comment: Awesome, this was indeed the problem. I've removed it and it's working. Now I just have to find a way to get that same functionality without preventing propagation. Do you want to post an answer so I can mark it?